# Unix Permission Issue

Tags: solaris-10

I am restarting the web logic services using my user-id but when I check the process owner and log files of web logic I can see the owner as root.

I have checked web logic side and am sure that it does not use root credentials internally.

Can you please suggest what am I missing to have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to restart Weblogic, and what are the actual processes started? Trace through the execution and you'll find some set-uid step. It may be in the Weblogic package itself, or a `su` (or `sudo`) step in a startup script.

Does your user-id have `sudo` privileges on the host?

Answer (score 0):

I am restarting the managed weblogic servers using the script and the command to restart the services is the usual one i.e.

java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://URL:Port -username **** -password ****  FORCESHUTDOWN  servername

java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://URL:Port -username **** -password ****  START servername

There is no sudo usage in the startup script.
When you say trace through execution and find set-uid what exactly does that mean? I have checked the weblogic server log and found that while initialization I could see user.name having value root being passed against it, where can I locate how this value is being assigned?